# beego models registered but not found

Tags: go, beego

I'm trying to write my first beego web app and I'm trying to register some models, i register them in `models/model.go`'s `init()` function, but when I run the command `bee run`, I get the following error:
`no Model found, need register your model`

**main.go**:

```
package main
import (
   "fmt"
    _ "test_blog/routers"
   "time"

   _ "github.com/lib/pq"

   "github.com/astaxie/beego"
   "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
)

func init() {
    orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DRPostgres)

    maxIdle := 30
    maxConn := 30
    orm.RegisterDataBase(
        "default",
        "postgres", 
        "postgres://user:password@localhost/test_db", maxIdle, maxConn
    )

    orm.DefaultTimeLoc = time.UTC
}

func main() {
    // Database alias.
    name := "default"

    // Drop table and re-create.
    force := false

    // Print log.
    verbose := false

    // Error.
    err := orm.RunSyncdb(name, force, verbose)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    beego.Run()
}
```

**Note**: `force` & `verbose` both were set to `true` before running `bee run` for the first time.

**models.go**:

```
package main

import "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"

type User struct {
    Name  string
    Posts []*Post `orm:"reverse(many)"`
}

type Post struct {
    Title   string    `orm:"size(50)"`
    Text    string    `orm:"size(4000)"`
    Created time.Time `orm:"auto_now_add;type(datetime)"`
    Updated time.Time `orm:"auto_now;type(datetime)"`
    Author  *User     `orm:"rel(fk)"`
}

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(User), new(Post))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

1. in models.go, change `package main` to `package models`
2. in main.go,  add `import _ "test_blog/models"`